# How to distinguish objects of derived classes C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Look at following code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    int aa = 1;
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    int bb = 2;
public:
    int getbb() { return bb; }
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    int cc = 3;
public:
    int getcc() { return cc; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    B b;
    C c;
    a.push_back(b);
    a.push_back(c);

    a[0].getbb(); //getbb() unaccessible;
    a[1].getcc(); //getcc() unaccessible;
}
```

`A` is the based class. `B` and `C` is the derived classes. I want to set a vector to hold either `B` or `C`, and use vector `a` to hold `A`. However, since `a` is a vector containing `A`'s objects, I can't access methods in `B` and `C`. Is there anyway to make `a[0].getbb()` and `a[1].getcc()` work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your vector of `A` is not capable of holding `B`s or `C`s, because it stores `A` by value, resulting in *object slicing* when `B` or `C` is stored. In particular, this means that when you store `B`, only `aa` gets stored; `bb` gets sliced away.

In order to store subclasses without slicing use a container of pointers - preferably, of *smart* pointers.

This wouldn't help you access functionality specific to `B` or `C` without a cast. One way to solve this problem is to give *virtual* member functions for `B`'s and `C`'s functionality to `A`, and make calls through `A`-typed reference of `B` or `C`.

Comment: Concerning the last remark, does `dynamic_cast`ing downward (and checking the result for null) help to call an non-virtual function specific to the child class?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make the compiler shut up by using a cast.  The resultant call (using a member function from `B` or `C`) has undefined behaviour though.

Comment: @Peter, my question is, if we use `dynamic_cast<B>` and check for null, can't we make sure that the object is actually a real B? (although I believe it would not be a good design choice).

Comment: That only works with pointers, A.S.H.   It doesn't work with converting an `A` to a `B`.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I am taking for granted the case where the vector is of type `A*` pointers :) and the actual objects might be any of A, B and C. (as suggested in the answer). Using dynamic_cast we may check if an element is of a certain type, i guess.

Comment: @A.S.H Yes, a non-null `dynamic_cast` guarantees a correct downcasting.

Answer (score 3):

Not without invoking undefined behaviour.

The problem is that `a.push_back(b)` and `a.push_back(c)` do not append objects `b` and `c` to the vector.   They create instances of `A` that hold only the "`A` parts".    This is called object slicing.

So there is no object of type `B` and no object of type `C` in the vector.

You force the issue and make your code compile by doing something like

```
 static_cast<B &>(a[0]).getbb();
```

but this just has undefined behaviour, since it treats `a[0]` as being of type `B` when it is really of type `A`.   Which makes it a really bad idea.   Although it will (probably) compile, it could do anything - and probably not what you expect.

If your vector contains `A *` rather than `A` it is possible.   For example;

```
  int main()
  {
       std::vector<A *> a;
       a.push_back(new B);
       a.push_back(new C);

       B* b = dynamic_cast<B *>(a[0]);
       if (b)    // if a[0] actually points at a B ....
          b->getbb();
       else
          complain_bitterly();

       C *c = dynamic_cast<C *>(a[1]);
       if (c)
          c->getcc();
       else
          complain_bitterly();
  }
```

Of course, doing this has practical trap doors as well - such as requiring class `A` having at least one `virtual member`.  It would be better off to work with a polymorphic base, and override virtual functions.

In other words, your design is broken, so fix it so it doesn't somehow require you to morph an object to a different type.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using pointers is to use a vector of [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)s and polymorphic classes. Small example below:

```
#include <functional> // for std::reference_wrapper
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void printme()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void printme() override
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C: public A
{
public:
    void printme() override
    {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> a;
    B b;
    C c;

    a.emplace_back(b);
    a.emplace_back(c);

    a[0].get().printme(); // need to "get()" the raw reference
    a[1].get().printme();
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82eaaf6ee1277fec)

Answer (score 2):

According the the cpp reference, there seems to be a way to achieve this by using `dynamic_cast`. You first need to make your vector a vector of **pointers** to the base class `A`. Then when accessing any element, you can check if it is a `B*` (or a `C*`) by checking the result of the `dynamic_cast` operator.

From the CPP reference:

> `dynamic_cast < new_type > ( expression )`
>
> ... If the cast is successful, dynamic_cast returns a value of type new_type. **If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type**...

Accordingly, you can do this:

```
std::vector<A*> a;
B b;
C c;
a.push_back(&b);
a.push_back(&c);
...
int i = something;
B* pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(a[i]); if(pB != nullptr) pb->getbb();
C* pC = dynamic_cast<C*>(a[i]); if(pC != nullptr) pC->getcc();
```

p.s: It is highly questionable as design approach though. The recommended OOP approach would be certainly to use a virtual method in the base class `A` and override it in `B` and `C`. But (hopefully) this answers the *exact* question as stated in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure they're instances of B and C, use cast:

```
static_cast<B>(a[0]).getbb();
static_cast<C>(a[1]).getcc();
```

Comment: That's not going to work, because `b` and `c` get sliced down to `A` on storing in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you may also create a vector of `A*`:

```
std::vector<A*> as;
as.push_back(new B);
as.push_back(new C);
B* b = (B*) as[0];
b->getbb();
c->getcc();
```

Now you only have to remember about freeing objects with `delete`.

Comment: That also has the problem that it treats `as[0]` as a `B *` whether it is actually a `B *` or not.   So the call of `b->getbb()` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter, remember if you are not sure if it is pointer to B or to A, **always** assert it's a pointer to A.

Comment: You can assert the sky is pink in your code, Jakub.   That doesn't make code work.

Comment: @Peter if you have a vector of `A`s, why you have an idea to treat any as a B?? See my answer that includes "sky colour".

Comment: It is not possible to treat an object of type `A` obtained from a `vector<A>` as if it is a `B`.

Comment: To complete the idea, is the following correct? `B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(as[anyIndex]); if (b != nullptr) b->getbb();`

Comment: @A.S.H, b should never be null, I'm scared if it points to an A or B object.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "Type IDs":

```
class A {
    // ...
    virtual int getTypeID() { return 0; }
}
class B {
    // ...
    virtual int getTypeID() { return 1; }
}
// analogically for C
```

It's virtual but is in prototype of A

Now use:

```
switch(a.getTypeID()) {
    case 0:
        // It's normal A
        break;
    case 1:
        // It's B
        // ...
        break;
    case 2:
        // It's C
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: See this answer and answer me if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: @sydridgm That's probably a tyoo, otherwise the virtuals don't make sense. Aside from that, this is a bad idea. Really bad design.

Comment: @JorenHeit But I think sometimes we need this kind of design

Comment: @sydridgm I truly doubt that.... C++ offers too many alternative applicable features for this kind of design to make sense.

Comment: @JorenHeit what alternative features?

Comment: Templates, virtual dispatch, RTTI. Different situations require different solutions of course, but the need to incorporate type information in a type is usually a sign that you need to reconsider your design.